# Express server reads JSON body incorrectly

Tags: java, node.js, json, express

Hi I'm trying to send a JSON file from a Java program to an Express server running on Node.js.

This is the Java method that's sending the JSON to the server:

```
public static void sendToSolver(String file) throws MalformedURLException {
try {
URL url = new URL("http://address/");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
con.setDoOutput(true);
try(OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream()) {
byte[] input = file.getBytes("utf-8");
os.write(input, 0, input.length);
}
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode() + " " + con.getResponseMessage());
con.disconnect();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

And this is the JSON that I'm sending to the server that is being generated with the JACKSon library. Copying it into a JSON validator yields no issues.

```
[ {
  "name" : "Game",
  "blocks" : [ {
    "shape" : [ 2, 2 ],
    "position" : [ 0, 1 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 2, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 0, 0 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 2, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 0, 3 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 2, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 2, 0 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 2, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 2, 3 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 1, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 2, 1 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 1, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 2, 2 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 1, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 3, 1 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 1, 1 ],
    "position" : [ 3, 2 ]
  }, {
    "shape" : [ 1, 2 ],
    "position" : [ 4, 1 ]
  } ]
} ]
```

And, finally, this is the simple express server that I'm using to receive this JSON:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json());
const port = 80

app.post('/', (req, res) =\> {
console.log(req.body);
res.send('Data received');
});
```

So when I try to send the JSON from the Java program I receive back a 200 response but the content of the request's body that gets printed from Node.js looks like this

```
[
  {
    name: 'Game',
    blocks: [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ]
  }
]
```

So the *name* field is being read without a problem, but then the following array is completely botched and it doesn't even contain ten fields like the original JSON.

I don't really understand how this happens as the JSON clearly gets sent but I can't see whether this issue is caused by the Java program or if that's an issue caused by express/Node.

Comment: That's showing you an array of ten objects, which is what you expected. Did you try accessing their contents, or otherwise _using_ the data?

Comment: It seems like the issue is with how the JSON array of blocks is being parsed on the Node.js server. Instead of an array of objects, it's being parsed as an array of arrays. Could you try to modify the Java program to generate a JSON object for each block, rather than a JSON array?

Comment: You claim "[the array] doesn't even contain ten fields" … but I count ten elements in the array shown by you. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` to serialize to JSON to a string again. `[Object object]` (but not `[Object]`) is how Objects are rendered in JavaScript by default.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried to save the request's body into a file to be fed to another node program but what I get is one line of [object] [Object]. So I'm not getting the results I was expecting to say the least.

Comment: @PeterTill I think I could but then I'd have to reconstruct the original JSON file into the Express server. Considering the scope of my project I'm not even sure that it'd be worth the hassle but I'll take a look into it.

Comment: @knittl that was the solution. Thanks a lot and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by knittl the solution is to use the `JSON.stringify(req.body)`
instruction to be able to handle the JSON in its original form.